# Javascript Recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am practicing recursion. Conceptually I understand how this should work, (see below) but my code isn't working.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. And please explain each step of your code and how it works. Clear Explanation is ten times better than just giving me code that works.

```
  /*
  buildList(0, 5) ==  buildList(0, 5 - 1) // [0]
  buildList(0, 4) ==  buildList(0, 4 - 1) // [0,0]
  buildList(0, 3) ==  buildList(0, 3 - 1) // [0,0,0]
  buildList(0, 2) ==  buildList(0, 2 - 1) // [0,0,0,0]
  buildList(0, 1) ==  buildList(0, 1 - 1) // [0,0,0,0,0]
  */

var buildList = function(value, length) {
    var result = [];
   if (length === 0) {
    return result;
   }

   result.push(value);

   return  buildList(result.push(value), length - 1);

};


buildList(0, 5);
```

I understand how recursion works on a conceptual level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach can't work, because the base case returns a new empty array, and other cases return the result of the recursion.

Instead, you should first recurse and then push

```
var buildList = function(value, length) {
  if (length <= 0) return [];
  var recur = buildList(value, length-1);
  recur.push(value);
  return recur;
};
```

Alternatively, in the base case you can avoid creating a new array

```
var buildList = function(value, length, array=[]) {
  if (length <= 0) return array;
  array.push(value);
  return buildList(value, length-1, array);
};
```

Comment: @spaceDog: The recursive call inside the alternative version is also in tail position that is, ES2015 compliant engines can optimize this call (tail call optimization). As a result the alternative version is as fast as an imperative loop.

Comment: @Iven I wasn't thinking about performance (because then a loop or `[].fill` would be better), but good point. [②ality](http://www.2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html) has a nice article about tail call optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with every call to your function, the `result` variable gets reinitialized to `[]`. If you declare that variable outside your function, the code works:

```
var result = [];
var buildList = function(value, length) {

   if(length === 0){
    return result;
   }

   result.push(value);

   return  buildList(result.push(value), length - 1);

};


buildList(0, 5);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not a very good solution. Imagine you want to build two lists, then both results would end up being a concatenation of the two lists you originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /*
  buildList(0, 5) ==  buildList(0, 5 - 1) // [0]
  buildList(0, 4) ==  buildList(0, 4 - 1) // [0,0]
  buildList(0, 3) ==  buildList(0, 3 - 1) // [0,0,0]
  buildList(0, 2) ==  buildList(0, 2 - 1) // [0,0,0,0]
  buildList(0, 1) ==  buildList(0, 1 - 1) // [0,0,0,0,0]
  */

var result = []; //(1)

var buildList = function(value, length) {
   if (length === 0) {
    return result;
   }

   result.push(value);

   return  buildList(value, length - 1);  //(2)

};


buildList(0, 5);
```

You're doing two things wrong:

1. You're initializing result inside the method.  This means every time the recursive method call is made, you're resetting result to an empty array.
2. You're passing the array into the recursive call of buildlist().  You want to be passing the value in there.

Comment: So the second time around making a list you'll end up with a concatenation. Not only that the first list you made have had a mutation since they are the same array...